# Android, Retrofit,RxJava - combine fields from multiple entities into single one

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2

Please look at my code below. My code to retrieve categories from city:

```
mcityAPI.authDevice(req)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMap(token -> mcityAPI.getCategories("/city/599/category",prepareHeaders(token)))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(categoryList->
                    {
                        HashMap<String, String> categoryNamesMap = new HashMap<>();
                        for (Category category : categoryList)
                        {
                            categoryNamesMap.put(category.getId(), category.getName());
                        }

                    }

                    , throwable ->
                    {
                        Throwable error = throwable;
                        String err = error.toString();
                    });
```

So, first device needs to be authorized - `authDevice`. Then, token needs to be provided to call `getCategories` (actually, token should be first transofrmed to headers by calling `prepareHeaders`)

So far, it works. I am able to succesfully load categories. Next step is to get events. In this case, I should call `/city/599/event`, but I need to do that as folloows:

- again provide headers (how to acces token retrieved previously?)
- my pojo model class for Event contains on extra field, called `categoryName`. Each returned event will contain field called `categoryId`. I have also added one extra field `categoryName`. For each returned category, I need to assign appropriate value to `categoryName` extra field. Category name should by retrieved from `categoryList` by `categoryId`

Is there any elegant way (some rxJava operator, etc) allowing to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your token is per device so you can store it to use it later.

So firstly:

- get your token and store it for e.g in SharedPreferences. This will give you access to token from every place you need.

Secondly:

- Now you can make both requests in the same stream.
- Remember to use `subscribeOn` correctly. It works only upstream and `observeOn` downstream. That means you are requesting on `MainTread` so you should change it.
- You can use operator map to get categoriesMap;
- You should take care of error handling, because one failure will unsubscribe your stream so cannot use it again.

```html
      triggerSubject
                    .flatMap(token -> mcityAPI.getCategories("/city/599/category",prepareHeaders(sharedPreferences.getToken())))
                    .map(categoryList -> {
                        final HashMap<String, String> categoryNamesMap = new HashMap<>();
                        for (Category category : categoryList)
                        {
                            categoryNamesMap.put(category.getId(), category.getName());
                        }
                        return categoryNamesMap;
                    })
                    .flatMap(cateogyrNameMap -> yourApiCall, prepareHeaders(sharedPreferences.getToken()))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .retry()
                    .subscribe(event -> {
                        // Do what you need
                    }

                    , throwable ->
                    {
                        Throwable error = throwable;
                        String err = error.toString();
                    });
```

Comment: What is `triggerSubject` ?

Comment: It is just example [subject] (http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) that triggers your requests. You can just stimulate (onNext() method) this subject to trigger your requests wherever you want

Comment: Can you provide sample how do you declare subject in this specific case? There is Subject<T> class, but I'm not sure which type is needed

Answer (score 1):

You could replicate the first part, flatmap it again and combine both observables with the [Zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

But it won't be very good in performance terms

What you can do is to use the same token observable in order to trigger both requests. So by transforming the first `Observable<Token>` into a hot observable you can use it without launching the request twice:

```
Observable<Token> obsToken = mcityAPI.authDevice(req)
                                 .share();       // So the authDevice method is only invoqued once
// Assumming your Category's ID is an Integer
Observable<Map<Integer, Category>> obsCategories = obsToken
                                           .flatMap(token -> mcityAPI.getCategories("/city/599/category",prepareHeaders(token)))
                                           .toList()     // So we have all categories
                                           .map(categoryList -> {
                                               Map<Integer, Category> result = new HashMap<>();
                                               for (Category c : categories)
                                                   result.put(c.getId(), c);
                                               return result;
                                           })
                                           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
Observable<List<Event>> obsEvents = obsToken
                                   .flatMap(token -> mcityAPI.getEvents("/city/599/eventprepareHeaders(token)))
                                   .toList()             // So we have all events
                                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
Observable<?> result = Observable.zip(obsCategories, obsEvents, (categories, events) -> {
    // now you have all categories and events
    // you can now fill category name by looking into the first map
    for (Event e : events)
        events.forEach(event -> 
            event.setCategoryName(
                categories.get(event.getCategoryId()).getName()
                )
        );
    // Do the rest of mapping and return something...
}
```

Comment: Do I really need to fill  categoryName for each event manually? I can't use any stream (or similar) api on Android and I'm not happy with ordinary for loop to determine categoryName for each event. Maybe RxJava could help me with it? (some operator that provides some kind of "dictionary", etc)

Comment: RxJava is not magic. It can't determine your necessities and provide and ad hoc solution. What you can do is to use the `Stream` api to collect your categories into a `Map` and access it via ID. I will update my answer

Comment: Any stream api is not allowed in my case. Stream api will only work on Android Nougat and my app will fail on any older Android, so not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong your comment. You can substitute any `stream()` related call with a `for` loop. I'll update

Comment: toList() seems to be not neccesary? Also, comipiler throws error "missing return statement" for zip operator. What to return?

Comment: I don't actually know what your service is returning. If it returns an `Observable<List<?>>` then you're right, `toList` is not necessaty. As per the `missing return statement` I don't know what you need to return so that's your task